# Make NHibernate use TRUNC for DateTime.Date

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have an entity with a `DateTime` property that is mapped to a table in an Oracle database.

The following query leads to NHibernate using a non-existent `date` function instead of `trunc`:

```
session.Query<MyEntity>().Where(x => x.MyProperty.Date = myDate);
```

The resulting SQL is something like this:

```
select <columns> from MY_ENTITY where date(MY_PROPERTY) = :p0;
```

How to tell NHibernate to use `trunc` instead?

I am using the ODP.NET provider of NHibernate (`OracleDataClientConfiguration.Oracle10`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This issue](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2914) was [fixed about a month ago](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/commit/4f21581c7155b41d40112a71a3fd686567bf03f4#src/NHibernate/Dialect/Oracle8iDialect.cs), but a stable version hasn't been released yet (as of 15/Feb/2012)

Until that happens, just inherit from `Oracle10gDialect` and register the function in the constructor:

```
RegisterFunction("date", new StandardSQLFunction("trunc", NHibernateUtil.Date));
```

Then configure NH to use the modified dialect.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did already in the meantime. Good to know it is fixed! :-)